# Starting 17:10 after upgrade

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

This morning my system decided to update to 17.10. All seemed to go well until I restarted.

The boot sequence got stuck on:

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean, 645143/457993280 files, 56503017/183143168 blocks
Starting Hostname Service...
```

Looked around and found that I might try to go through Grub. Some of the results:

```
[3.707132] platform wdat_wdt: failed to claim resource 4
...
[3770183] ACPI: watchdog: Failed to create platform device
```

I tried something else later (don't ask what - I am not too confident on this stuff) and got this:

```
grep: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory.
```

From grub I tried `dpkg` to no avail, it's telling me it will take several hours (fine) but every action fails. No network I assume. I then go to network and... see 4 above for each and every one of the commands.

I then tried to reboot from a USB running 10.04 and no problem, it works but... is there anyway from there that I can access my data. It looks like a brand new thing and can't see any documents/pictures/music etc.

I would really appreciate it if I didn't have to reformat and start afresh.

Comment: Reinstalling is rarely needed. However, It's very difficult to tell what you did - please use the formatting tools to show output clearly, and please be much more specific about how dpkg failed. Why were you using dpkg instead of apt? What did you try and what were the exact failures?

Comment: Thank you user535733. OK, not sure where to find the formatting tool, so I apologise if it is unclear. I guess I panicked a little when I couln't start after an update. I googled and google and tried whatever I could find, which is probably why I used dpkg. I can access Grubb but no options seems to do anything. What exactly should I do in your opinion? And yes, regarding the last part of my initial question I "discovered" that I can access the partition where 17:10 data is.

Comment: Much of what you describe seems normal. Other elements are outlandish (your system 'decided' to upgrade itself). Others are plain bizzarre (somehow dpkg doesn't work while you can't even boot because grub does nothing). Are you able to boot, or not? Are you able to use network, or not? Are you able to use the package manager, or not?

Comment: OK, I might have not expressed myself clearly. Obviously, it was an automated update (I guess). In the system setting it shows that the update function will be checked daily. Yes, I can boot and access grub. Yes, I can boot and choose which partition to start from. 10:4 fires up... and from there I can access my documents on 17:10 but I cannot not start from 17:10. Thank you again for your help and finally no, I cannot access network.

Comment: Hmmm. There is no such thing as an 'automated' release-upgrade...unless your system has been haywired in a pretty amazing way...so that's a bit confusing and perhaps a whole different problem. It seems like you have multiple releases of Ubuntu installed on different partitions (nothing wrong there). Is one of them really 10.04 (that would be bad)? When you select 17.10 to boot from grub, what happens? What do you see and hear? Did you remember to disable the Plymouth splash screen so you can see all the details of the boot?

Comment: Errrrrmmmmm, another silly moment. Sorry. No, NOT 10.04 but 17.04.My mistake. I'll try again from grub to boot from 17.10 and report. No idea what the Plymouth splash scree is, how to disable it and how to gather the details of the boot. And again, that you so much for your help. Anyway to insert a screen shot on here?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to amend, clarify and add information? Also, it would explained what *exactly* happens now when you (try to) boot your system, e. g. what's the last thing to see on the display before it becomes stuck or, if there's not much to see, what the last notable thing to see on the display was. As it stands, your question tells a story about issues that don't appear any longer and then doesn't explain what happens now.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your reply but in the end, I reformated and reinstalled afresh. All good now.